# Can't get lx-select to display data

Tags: angularjs, lumx

I have the following select:

```
<lx-select ng-model="selects.selectedPerson" placeholder="Recommended by" choices="people" floating-label>
    <lx-select-selected>{{ $selected.name + ' ' + $selected.age }}</lx-select-selected>

    <lx-select-choices>{{ $choice.email }}</lx-select-choices>
</lx-select>
```

and the following $scope variables:

```
$scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 10 },
    { name: 'Amalie', email: 'amalie@email.com', age: 12 }
    ];
```

But when I run this code there are no results in this dropdown.  I can click the dropdown and the ripple effects occurs but no dropdown appears and no choices are ever selected.

What am I missing?

Comment: What versions of each are you using. Until recently, LumX templates weren't compatible with the latest version of angular-formly

Comment: I'm using the latest LumX.  I'm not incorporating Formly just yet.

Comment: @kentcdodds Maybe I'll try incorporating LumX templates and Formly together and see if this issue fixes itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Haha, I noticed you asked your question in the formly chat and assumed you were already using formly :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read that LumX has a known issue when using Bootstrap in addition to the bootstrap that comes with LumX.  I removed the reference to the nonLumX one and it took off.